# Wrong aspect ratio for video sent with WhatsApp (only when trimmed)

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, video

When I take videos with my Sony Alpha 5000 and transfer them to my Android device, the aspect ratio looks fine in all players tested (F-Stop, VLC, MX Player Pro, ES Media-Player).

When I send such a video with WhatsApp and keep the full length, it still looks fine. But when I change the video length in WhatsApp before sending, the video will be sent with a wrong aspect ratio (squeezed):

[image: Screenshot of a video of a cube sent via WhatsApp]

(Top message: full video; second message: trimmed video played with a wrong aspect ratio)

This is a link to the video in case you want to reproduce what I did:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ovp1j9mmb49exq2/MAH05890.MP4?dl=1

Has anybody observed this issue, too? Is something wrong with my video file?

**EDIT**:

I have recorded another video in landscape mode and replaced the original screenshot/video link in order to make clear that this issue is not related to a wrong video orientation in this video's metadata.

Comment: Looks to me more like a landscape/portrait problem. My guess would be that the video contained a marker that it has been recorded in portrait orientation and the WhatsApp video editor has removed the flag which makes the video players display the video in wrong orientation.

Comment: I see the wrong orientation in every video player. It looks like WhatsApp can't rotate videos. But meanwhile I found an app called "Smart Video Rotate and Flip" that can rotate my video by just changing metadata. But even with the right orientation, WhatsApp squeezes my video when I trim it.